# Python+Selenium. Ожидание загрузки страницы

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как на примере данного простого кода реализовать ожидание загрузки страницы? Например ждёт 20 секунд и если не загрузилась то пишет сообщение и  идёт на выход. Заранее спасибо.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser=webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('http://yandex.ru')
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set_page_load_timeout
```

В данном случае может не помочь, т.к. устанавливает время, которое мы будем ждать, пока страница загрузится, но не *конкретно* загрузку страницы. Я бы порекомендовал сначала вычленить критерий загрузки страницы полностью, например, появление какого-либо элемента на ней, и уже это принять за правду - страница загружена. Так Можно будет написать:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

browser=webdriver.PhantomJS()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 500)
browser.get('http://yandex.ru')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "text")))
browser.quit()
```

**UPD:**
или использовать другой критерий, например `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "text")))`

Comment: Я бы попросил бы вас дополнить ответ краткой теоретической вставкой о том, что это Явное Ожидание, и что есть это ещё Неявное, и что вся эта информация содержится в документации по Selenium на англ вот тут - http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

на рус вот тут - https://habrahabr.ru/post/273089/.

Всё таки мы же хотим что-бы человек учился))

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это то, что вы ищете
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout

Comment: Добавте немного информации от себя, почему вы считаете, что ссылка поможет автору вопроса в решении.